# Alternative to android scrollview?

Tags: android, android-widget

I need a scrollable view on android, but it cannot be a scrollview, because the views I am adding to it is bugging when I use inside scrollview. If I dynamically add those views to a simple linear layout, I cannot see all the views because they are longer than the screen height.

The views I am adding dynamically are android widgets. The app I am developing is quite a simple launcher, so it needs to be able to handle app widgets. But I dont want to use view pager. I need it scrollable like a scrollview.

Note: I tried listview but it is the same issue: some widgets are bugging.

[Inside a linearlayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gnRu.jpg)

[Inside scrollview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/So5NS.jpg)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `widgets are bugging` how exactly?

Comment: Have you checked Recycler View?

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I edited my answer with pictures. I changed the background to red so you can see that black shadow.

Comment: @MuhammadHashimShafiq I didn't tried with RecyclerView, but I think it is the same as ListView, right?

Comment: Its not exactly same as ListView. Function wise you can say but it is advance version of ListView. Check Recycler View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is the solution

I tried using listview, recyclerview and scrollview. None of them influenced on the bug.

The problem is that I was using wrap_content on the widget's parent, and some of them just had that behavior. So widget's height have to be a value independent to the widget's content, so it cannot be wrap_content.

Thank you guys that tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to hold your content xml in one layout as child of scrollview?

```
<ScrollView>

   <LinearLayout>

//your all xml here

   </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I tried. Got the same bug. Check my edited question to see the what happens.